# RTMP streaming not working with fluent-ffmpeg and gl

Tags: node.js, typescript, opengl, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to send opengl rendering results to rtmp using gl and fluent-ffmpeg packages.
The render function writes opengl output to glBuf.
And the render function is called about 60 times per second.
And it calls ffmpeg with that glBuf as input.

```js
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import GL from "gl";
import { env } from "./env";
import { PassThrough } from "stream";

const WIDTH = 1920;
const HEIGHT = 1080;
const gl = GL(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

const glBuf = new PassThrough();
const render = () => {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  const pixels = new Uint8Array(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  glBuf.write(pixels);
};

const FRAMES = 10;
setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < FRAMES; i++) {
    render();
  }
}, FRAMES * 1.1 * (1000 / 60));

ffmpeg()
  .input(glBuf)
  .inputFormat("rawvideo")
  .inputOptions([`-video_size ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}`, "-pix_fmt rgba"])
  .inputFPS(60)
  .outputFormat("flv")
  .outputOptions([
    "-c:v libx264",
    "-preset veryfast",
    "-maxrate 3000k",
    "-bufsize 6000k",
    "-pix_fmt yuv420p",
    "-g 60",
    "-c:a aac",
    "-b:a 160k",
    "-ac 2",
  ])
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .output(`${env.stream_url}/${env.stream_key}`)
  .run();
```

However, stream health shows No data. That is, the data is ignored.
[Not works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkucE.png)

So I modified the code to save flv file. It works then.

```
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import GL from "gl";
import { env } from "./env";
import { PassThrough } from "stream";

const WIDTH = 1920;
const HEIGHT = 1080;
const gl = GL(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

const glBuf = new PassThrough();
const render = () => {
  gl.viewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  const pixels = new Uint8Array(WIDTH * HEIGHT * 4);
  gl.readPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  glBuf.write(pixels);
};

const FRAMES = 10;
const renderInterval = setInterval(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < FRAMES; i++) {
    render();
  }
}, FRAMES * 1.1 * (1000 / 60));

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(renderInterval);
  glBuf.end();
  console.log("done!");
}, 3000);

ffmpeg()
  .input(glBuf)
  .inputFormat("rawvideo")
  .inputOptions([`-video_size ${WIDTH}x${HEIGHT}`, "-pix_fmt rgba"])
  .inputFPS(60)
  .outputFormat("flv")
  .outputOptions([
    "-c:v libx264",
    "-preset veryfast",
    "-maxrate 3000k",
    "-bufsize 6000k",
    "-pix_fmt yuv420p",
    "-g 60",
    "-c:a aac",
    "-b:a 160k",
    "-ac 2",
  ])
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .output(`output.flv`)
  .run();
```

[It works then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lo8.png)

Why doesn't first code work?